# Copiar nombre del archivo seleccionado

Tags: javascript

Tengo este pequeño JS que me permite copiar el nombre del archivo seleccionado a la caja de filtro, él funciona bien, pero me gustaría que solo se copiaran a la caja de filtro, las palabras claves, es decir, que se ignoraran las palabras 1 o 2 letras como "y", "o", "de", "la", etc., así como los números y caracteres (paréntesis, asteriscos, comas, guiones, etc.).

Imagino que esto pueda ser resuelto editando el final de la penúltima línea:
`replace(/ /g, '|')` por medio de expresiones regulares, pero llevo días estudiando e intentando de todo y no lo consigo.

`([a-zA-Z]+)\s`

`[^ .,;-_()]`

```
function OnClick(clickData) {
    var cmd = clickData.func.command;
    var tab = clickData.func.sourcetab;
    var fsu = DOpus.FSUtil();
    cmd.deselect = false;
    if (tab.selected.count == 0) return;
    cmd.RunCommand('Set QUICKFILTER="(' + fsu.NewWild().EscapeString(tab.selected(0).name_stem).replace(/ /g, '|') + ')"');
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este otro script que permite hacer casi lo mismo, este sí permite ignorar ciertos caracteres como "," ";" pero tiene la desventaja, para mí, que lo que copia a la caja de Filtro es el contenido del portapapeles y no el nombre del archivo seleccionado.

Si en este script se pudiera remplazar la variable que captura el contenido del portapapeles, que creo que es `var tmp = DOpus.GetClip();` por la que captura el nombre del archivo seleccionado en el otro script, que lamentablemente no sé, creo que el problema estaría resuelto.

```js
function OnClick(clickData) {
    if (DOpus.GetClipFormat() != 'text') return;
    var cmd = clickData.func.command;
    cmd.deselect = false;
    var tmp = DOpus.GetClip();
    tmp = DOpus.FSUtil().NewWild().EscapeString(tmp); // Escape characters used in standard pattern matching
    // out-comment as needed
    tmp = tmp.replace(/;/g, '|');
    tmp = tmp.replace(/,/g, '|');
    tmp = tmp.replace(/ /g, '|');
    tmp = tmp.replace(/\r/g, '|'); // return
    tmp = tmp.replace(/\n/g, '|'); // line feed
    tmp = tmp.replace(/\t/g, '|'); // tab
    // here would be the place to insert additional replacements
    tmp = tmp.replace(/\|+/g, '|'); // clean up duplicate |
    tmp = tmp.replace(/^\||\|$/g, ''); // remove leading and trailing |
    var cmdLine = 'Set QUICKFILTER="(' + tmp + ')"';
    // DOpus.Output(cmdLine);
    cmd.RunCommand(cmdLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Ejemplo

Puedes probar con `split`-`filter`-`join`.

Código JavaScript:

```js
console.log("05. Libros leídos (Mayo)"
            .split(/\P{L}/gu)
            .filter(w=>w.length > 2)
            .join('|')
           );
```

La función `split` nos extrae palabras con solo letras.

La función `filter` nos descarta palabras de menos de 2 caracteres.

La función `join` junta las palabras con el caracter `|`.

#### Corrección del método `OnClick`

```js
cmd.RunCommand('Set QUICKFILTER="(' + fsu.NewWild().EscapeString(tab.selected(0).name_stem)
.split(/\P{L}/gu).filter(w=>w.length>2).join('|') + ')"');
```

---

En relación al error que aparece ahora, desconozco si el API de QuickFilters (no localizo su documentación para desarrolladores) limita algunas opciones de expresiones regulares.

Puedes aplicar la solución presentada en [esta publicación externa](https://resource.dopus.com/t/set-quickfilter-from-clipboard/40606). Consiste en ejecutar varios `replace`-s. He vuelto a incluir split-filter-join sin el modificador `u` en la expresión regular.

```js
function OnClick(clickData) {
    var cmd = clickData.func.command;
    var tab = clickData.func.sourcetab;
    var fsu = DOpus.FSUtil();
    var texto = fsu.NewWild().EscapeString(tab.selected(0).name_stem);
    
    // Sustituir caracteres no deseados por un espacio
    texto = texto.replace(/\(/g, ' ');
    texto = texto.replace(/\)/g, ' ');
    texto = texto.replace(/\./g, ' ');
    
    // Descartar textos cortos (0 a 2 caracteres)
    var textos = texto.split(/\s+/g);
    var textosLargos = [];
    for(var indice = 0; indice < textos.length; indice++){
      if(textos[indice].length > 2){
        textosLargos.push(textos[indice]);
      }
    }
    texto = textosLargos.join('|');

    cmd.deselect = false;
    if (tab.selected.count == 0) return;
    
    // Finalmente, usamos el texto para el filtro
    cmd.RunCommand('Set QUICKFILTER="(' + texto + ')"');
}
```

#### Referencias

- [RegExp Unicode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode)
- [Unicode character class escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Unicode_character_class_escape)

Comment: Hola nonas, primero que todo gracias por la ayuda, pero sustituí la línea que me corrigió y se genera el siguiente error.

Error en la línea 7, posición 108
...d(0).name_stem).split(/\P{L}/gu).filter(w=>w.length>2).join(...
                                  ^
Se esperaba ')' (0x800a03ee)
Error de análisis - script abortado

Comment: Añadí una posible corrección.

Comment: Hola @padaleiana, casi lo conseguimos, que buen trabajo, dio un error en la línea 13, posición 42; y eliminé la parte comprometida **filter(w=>w.length>2)** y funciona perfectamente bien. Ahora estudiaré con más calma por qué ese bloque está dando error, mil veces gracias!

Comment: Existe alguna otra forma para ignorar palabras de 1-3 letras? Tipo **[a-zA-Z]{3}**

Comment: @Daso nada tengo que ver con el código (podés revisarlo haciendo clic en donde dice "editada hace <tiempo>") :)

Comment: Si, en lugar del método **filter** puedes usar una estructura condicional. He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto @nonas, el script ahora quedó perfecto, muchas, muchas gracias, estoy feliz y eso te lo debo a ti!!!